# Directed Graph $D$ has a Directed Path of At Least $\chi_u$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I've been working on some problems related to directed graphs in my computer
science course, and I have been somewhat stumped on this one particular problem.
Take a directed graph $D$, and consider its underlying undirected graph
$D_{u}$ (as in, the graph that is made when we take every directed edge in $D$
and turn it into an undirected edge. I am trying to prove that if $D_{u}$ has
a chromatic number of $\chi_u,$ then there exists a directed path in $D$ that
is of length at least $\chi_u$.

Here is my argument so far. If the chromatic coloring of $D_{u}$ is
$\chi_u$, this means that there is a $K_{\chi_u}$ in $D_u$. This means that
there are $\chi_u$ vertices in $D$ that are all adjacent in some directions.
However, I am having some issues casing from this part. Say there is some
vertex that only has out-edges; should I start constructing the pact from here?
This would imply that this is the only vertex that has all out-edges, but I am
not completely sure how to form this construction.

Comment: I am a little confused. Consider the triangle graph, with one vertex having indegree 2. The chromatic number is 3, but the biggest path has length 2

Comment: May be what you want to know is the Gallai–Hasse–Roy–Vitaver theorem